# Spark fastest way for creating RDD of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My spark application is using RDD's of numpy arrays.
At the moment, I'm reading my data from AWS S3, and its represented as 
a simple text file where each line is a vector and each element is seperated by space, for example:

```
1 2 3
5.1 3.6 2.1
3 0.24 1.333
```

I'm using numpy's function `loadtxt()` in order to create a numpy array from it.

However, this method seems to be very slow and my app is spending too much time(I think) for converting my dataset to a numpy array.

Can you suggest me a better way for doing it? For example, should I keep my dataset as a binary file?,
should I create the RDD in another way?

Some code for how I create my RDD:

```
data = sc.textFile("s3_url", initial_num_of_partitions).mapPartitions(readData)
```

readData function:

```
 def readPointBatch(iterator):
     return [(np.loadtxt(iterator,dtype=np.float64)]
```

Comment: One possible reason for being slow could be that your file is not splitted. Cut your input into multiple files on s3 and use a wildcard to match them all in your url.

Comment: @PaulK.What do you mean not splitted? if my files are file1.txt file2.txt and so on, so the url will be s3n://bucket//file*.txt  ?

Comment: You don't really give use enough to go on here. What makes you think that `numpy` is really a problem here? If you read files and just split on whitespaces `data = sc.textFile("s3_url").map(str.split)` is it significantly faster?

Comment: @zero323 numpy is a problem because it's loadtxt function is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do under these circumstances is to use pandas library for io.

Please refer to this question : [pandas read_csv() and python iterator as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927320/pandas-read-csv-and-python-iterator-as-input/33986924#33986924)
.

There you will see how to replace the `np.loadtxt()` function so it would be much faster to 
create a RDD of numpy array.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a little bit more idiomatic and slightly faster to simply map with `numpy.fromstring` as follows:

```
import numpy as np.

path = ...
initial_num_of_partitions = ...

data = (sc.textFile(path, initial_num_of_partitions)
   .map(lambda s: np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.float64, sep=" ")))
```

but ignoring that there is nothing particularly wrong with your approach. As far as I can tell, with basic configuration, it is roughly twice a slow a simply reading the data and slightly slower than creating dummy numpy arrays.

So it looks like the problem is somewhere else. It could be cluster misconfiguration, cost of fetching data from S3 or even unrealistic expectations.

Comment: It's well known that numpy's loadtxt is very slow.
The read_csv() function from pandas library is super fast compared to that.
Unfortunately, It's cannot accept a python generator as an input, like np.loadtxt(). Also, I have to use mapPartitions because I look at the whole chunk of the points at each partition, and not point by point.
The problem is that i'm getting access to the txt file only by a generator.

Comment: Compared to the cost of running task it is negligible and like I've mentioned above at least with basic benchmarking it is at most 30% slower than simply initializing arrays. Regarding partitions - `SparkContext.textFile` doesn't create meaningful partitions so any logic that simply looks at the partition is faulty by design.

Comment: If I could use pandas read_csv() it was 60% faster.
What do you mean that SparkContext.textFile doesn't create meaningful partitions? I just need it to spread the text file between partitions.

Comment: How much data per worker do you load? And what is the current and expected loading time?

Comment: I mean that content of the partitions will vary depending on a configuration, source an other factors. On a side note it is possible create pandas data frame per partition.

Comment: Each partition is 10mb of my data. I except up to 10 sec for creating a numpy array from it.

Comment: It take less than 2s to process 32MB per partition on my server. If you struggle to get below 10s it is most likely a configuration problem.

Comment: r u using np.loadtxt() function?

Comment: Nope, `np.fromstring`.

Comment: `np.fromstring` doesn't help me because I need to map the whole partition into 1 array, not each line to array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96464/discussion-between-zero323-and-member555).

Comment: btw, what's the difference your np.fromstring() approace to : np.array([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')])?
because that's seems slow to me as well

Comment: For starters at least one type conversion. But like I said before - majority of work seems to be creating numpy arrays not parsing itself. Pandas may be faster because it needs only an array per column, not per row.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `numpy` while working with Spark. Spark has its own methodology of processing data assuring that your sometimes really big files aren't loaded into memory at once, exceeding the memory limit. You should load your file like this with Spark:

```
data = sc.textFile("s3_url", initial_num_of_partitions) \
    .map(lambda row: map(lambda x: float(x), row.split(' ')))
```

Now this will output an `RDD` like this, based on your example:

```
>>> print(data.collect())
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [5.1, 3.6, 2.1], [3.0, 0.24, 1.333]]
```

---

**@edit** Some suggestions on file formats and `numpy` usage:

Text files are just as good as CSV, TSV, Parquet or anything you feel comfortable with. Binary files are not preferred, according to the Spark docs on binary files loading:

> **binaryFiles**(*path*, *minPartitions=None*)
>
> **Note:** Experimental
>
> Read a directory of binary files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI as a byte array. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.
>
> Note: Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.

As for `numpy` usage, if I were you I'd deffinitely tried to replace any external package with native Spark, for example `pyspark.mlib.random` for randomization: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.random

Comment: My alg for spark is using numpy matrix multiplication and random functions.
It will be very inconvenient for me to use your way for representing a vector.

Also, I asked about whether should I keep my file as a text file, or whether should I use some other format for better performance.

Thanks

Comment: Text files are just as good as CSV, TSV, Parquet or anything you feel comfortable with. Binary files are not prefered, according to the Spark docs on binary files loading: `Note: Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.`

Comment: As for `numpy` usage, if I were you I'd deffinitely tried to replace any external package with native Spark, for example `pyspark.mlib.random` for randomization: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.random

Comment: my files aren't key value. I understand it's better to use native Spark, but I don't see other options than using numpy at the moment.
So what the best way to keep a file of size GB's which represents a vector? do you think txt file will be good?

Comment: Hi Nhor, didn't work to me. I've created a simple npy file with: matrix = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [5.1, 3.6, 2.1], [3.0, 0.24, 1.333]]) np.save("/tmp/test",matrix) and then upload to S3. Now, I am trying to read it with your code snippet and get the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string. Any idea what I am doing wrong?