# pandas read_csv() and python iterator as input

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to use pandas read_csv() func where the input is a python iterator,
where each next() will bring to the next line of my text file.
What would you suggest me to do? I want best performance.

As I understood, StringIO works in that case, but i would rather to not use that.

BTW, after that I'm using as_matrix() function in order to create a numpy array.
Doing so because it's much faster than np.loadtxt() func which is horribly slow :(

Comment: Why the iterator, why not the file object?

Comment: @MaxNoe because i can get access to the content of the txt file only by a generator

Comment: Just because i'm curious: Where does this strange limitation come from?

Comment: @MaxNoe I'm working with Apache Spark and my big text file is distributed across the nodes in my cluster. I want to do compute some function on each part of the text file at each node. The way I get access to that part is only by a python's iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use :

```
 from io import StringIO
 pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(iter)))
```

where `iter` is your iterator / generator variable.
This is still faster than using `np.loadtxt(iter)`