# Spark with python - numpy is slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to calculate 1 round of K-Means.
I have k centers, and I just want for each point of the input to know who is the closest center to it.
Also, I want to know the sum of squared distances(Cost of K-Means).

The code is like the following:

```
    points = sc.textFile("s3_url",20).map(parseVector).cache()
    closest = points.map(lambda p: (distanceToClosest(p, means)))
    cost = closest.reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

the `means` variable is hard-wired.

Where `parseVector` is like that:

```
def parseVector(line):
    return np.fromstring(line, dtype=np.float64, sep=" ")
```

and distanceToClosest is:

```
def distanceToClosest(p, centers):
    closest = float("+inf")
    for i in range(len(centers)):
        tempDist = np.sum((p - centers[i]) ** 2)
        if tempDist < closest:
            closest = tempDist
    return closest
```

My input is only 5GB and I'm using 10 cores, and still this easy operation takes 10+min! When I'm expecting 1 min.

Comment: @zero323 everything including reduce. its not 10 min, its actually 30min..

Comment: Both fetching data from S3 and parsing is slow so it is not particularly surprising. Not to mention it looks like (or is `float` `np.float`?)  you mix numpy and standard numerics and don't vectorize search. What is the type of `centers`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using 10 cores with Python? Are you using multiprocessing package or something else to achieve parallel processing?

Comment: @zero323 centers is a numpy array.  I understand it's not fast. But that slow?

Comment: @V.K. I'm using 5 nodes on ec2, each node has 2 cores

Comment: @zero323 fetching from s3 is not such a big problem. I think that distanceToClosest(p, centers) is the problem..

Comment: If so how about `centers[np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(centers - p, axis=1))]`?

Comment: For large sets of data calling numpy will do it in sequential manner. As data increases your preprocessing will be scalable but the main part of project will be a bottle neck to the numpy function.  For speed you may want to consider doing the np function yourself.

Comment: @InkSlob you mean that creating a numpy arrays is very expensive?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804380/spark-fastest-way-for-creating-rdd-of-numpy-arrays?rq=1 I tried to discuss it here

Comment: Try "Mining Massive Datasets" by Leskovec, Rajaraman, and Ullman. Chapter 7 covers clustering, pg 254 is k-means.  Book focuses on designing algorithms for parallel design.  [link](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf)

Comment: @InkSlob Using NumPy doesn't affect Spark parallelism here.

Comment: Do you have access to scipy? scipy has much more efficient implementations for nearest-neighbour searches and k-means clustering (see [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree) and [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans) respectively).

Comment: BTW Do you have any particular reason to avoid `mllib.kmeans`?

Comment: @zero323 I already got the KMeans.. I want to calc the cost

Comment: @zero323 Why does creating an RDD where each partition is a numpy array is much slower than creating RDD of Vector from Scala mllib ?

Comment: Benefits of static typing plus the fact that `mllib.Vector` in Scala is nothing else than a wrapper around `Array[Double]`